# Convert structure to byte array in .NET

Tags: vb.net, marshalling, arrays

I wish to write a structure made up of fixed length strings to a file using My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes or the like.

I am using a VB6 project with fixed length strings that I have converted in to VB.Net.

```
    Structure Record
        <VBFixedString(22),System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValArray,SizeConst:=22)> Public tim() As Char
        <VBFixedString(130),System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValArray,SizeConst:=130)> Public des() As Char
        <VBFixedString(2),System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValArray,SizeConst:=2)> Public crlf() As Char
    End Structure
```

Still new to marshalling in C#, but how would I get this structure to an array of bytes to write to a file.  Is there some marshalling trick or am I going to have to write a custom method?

Comment: As a side note, a structure is not a reference type. It's a value type.

Comment: Changed in title.  I knew that but for some reason still wrote reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use serialization mechanisms provided by the .NET framework:

```
Dim formatter As New BinaryFormatter
formatter.Serialize(outputFileStream, objectInstance)
```

You should add `<Serializable()>` attribute to your type.

Comment: @dnh828, To add to @Mehrdad's answer, also make sure all the types in the object graph you are trying to convert are decorated with the [Serializable] attribute...

Comment: How do I apply the serializable attribute to these fixed length strings?

Comment: You don't need to. Just apply it to the `Structure`. `Char` arrays are serializable.