# Marshal.Copy not copying from bytes array into structure starting at the address provided in an IntPtr

Tags: .net, vb.net, copy, marshalling, intptr

(This is in some sense a follow-up question to [Extracting structs in the middle of a file into my structures other than accessing the file byte for byte and compose their value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49920732/how-do-i-extract-structs-in-the-middle-of-a-file-into-my-structures-other-than-a?noredirect=1#comment86858787_49920732).)

I am having a file containing a structure record in its stream:

```
[Start]...[StructureRecord]...[End]
```

The contained structure fits into this layout, of which exists a variable:

```
Public Structure HeaderStruct
    Public MajorVersion As Short
    Public MinorVersion As Short
    Public Count As Integer         
End Structure

private grHeaderStruct As HeaderStruct
```

It is into this variable I want a copy of the structure residing in the file.

Required namespaces:

```
'File, FileMode, FileAccess, FileShare:
Imports System.IO

'GCHandle, GCHandleType:
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

'SizeOf, Copy:
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal
```

My `FileStream` is named `oFS`.

```
Using oFS = File.Open(sFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    ...
```

Assume, that `oFS` is positioned at the start of `[StructureRecord]` now.

So there are 8 bytes (`HeaderStruct.Length`) to read from the file, and copy these into a record instance of this structure. To do so, I wrap the logic to read from file the required number of bytes and transfer them to my structure record into a generic method `ExtractStructure`. The destination is instantiated just before the call to the routine.

```
    grHeaderStruct = New HeaderStruct
    ExtractStructure(Of HeaderStruct)(oFS, grHeaderStruct)
    ...
End Using
```

(Before suggesting techniques to read just these 8 bytes outside of a dedicated method, you should probably know, that the whole file consists of structures, which depend on each other. The `Count` field says, that 3 child structures are to follow, but these contain `Count` fields themselves, etc. I think a routine to get them is not a too bad idea.)

However, this is the routine which causes my current head-ache:

```
'Expects to find a structure of type T at the actual position of the 
'specified filestream oFS. Reads this structure into a byte array and copies
'it to the structure variable specified in oStruct.
Public Shared Sub ExtractStructure(Of T As Structure) _
    (oFS As FileStream, ByRef oStruct As T)

    Dim oGCHandle As GCHandle
    Dim oStructAddr As IntPtr
    Dim iStructLen As Integer
    Dim abStreamData As Byte()

    'Obtain a handle to the structure, pinning it so that the garbage
    'collector does not move the object. This allows the address of the 
    'pinned structure to be taken. Requires the use of Free when done.
    oGCHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(oStruct, GCHandleType.Pinned)

    Try
        'Retrieve the address of the pinned structure, and its size in bytes.
        oStructAddr = oGCHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject
        iStructLen = SizeOf(oStruct)

        'From the file's current position, obtain the number of bytes 
        'required to fill the structure.
        ReDim abStreamData(0 To iStructLen - 1)
        oFS.Read(abStreamData, 0, iStructLen)

        'Now both the source data is available (abStreamData) as well as an 
        'address to which to copy it (oStructAddr). Marshal.Copy will do the
        'copying.
        Marshal.Copy(abStreamData, 0, oStructAddr, iStructLen)
    Finally
        'Release the obtained GCHandle.
        oGCHandle.Free()
    End Try
End Sub
```

The instruction

```
oFS.Read(abStreamData, 0, iStructLen)
```

does read the correct number of bytes with the correct values, as per immediate window:

```
?abstreamdata
{Length=8}
    (0): 1
    (1): 0
    (2): 2
    (3): 0
    (4): 3
    (5): 0
    (6): 0
    (7): 0
```

I can not use `Marshal.StructureToPtr` here, because, well, a bytes array is not a structure. However, the `Marshal` class has also a `Copy` method.

Only that I obviously miss a point here, because

```
Marshal.Copy(abStreamData, 0, oStructAddr, iStructLen)
```

does **not** do the intended copy (but it also does not throw an exception):

```
?ostruct
    Count: 0
    MajorVersion: 0
    MinorVersion: 0
```

**What do I fail to understand, why this copy is not working?**

The MS documentation does not tell too much for Marshal.Copy: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146625(v=vs.110).aspx:

> source - Type: System.Byte() 
>   The one-dimensional array to copy from.
>
> startIndex - Type: System.Int32 
>   The zero-based index in the source array where copying should start.
>
> destination - Type: System.IntPtr 
>   The memory pointer to copy to.
>
> length - Type: System.Int32 
>   The number of array elements to copy.

Looks as if I have set up right everything, so is it possible that `Marshal.Copy` does not copy to the structure, but to some other place?

`oStructAddr` surely does look like an address (&H02EB7B64), but where is that?

**Edit**

Between the instantiation of the parameter receiving the result and the call to the routine

```
    grHeaderStruct = New HeaderStruct
    ExtractStructure(Of HeaderStruct)(oFS, grHeaderStruct)
```

I filled the instantiated record with some test data to see whether it is actually passed correctly:

```
#Region "Test"
    With grMultifileDesc
        .MajorVersion = 7
        .MinorVersion = 8
        .Count = 9
    End With
#End Region
```

In the procedure, I check the value of the record before and after `Marshal.Copy` in the immediate window. Both times I obtain:

```
?ostruct
{MyProject.MyClass.HeaderStruct}
    Count: 9
    MajorVersion: 7
    MinorVersion: 8
```

(Re-arrangement of the record's fields is the same in the caller as in the callee, which of course is an issue in itself, as the data is read from a file and would be wrongly copied into the structure. However, this is not the topic of the question.)

Conclusion: Data obtained, but no `Marshal.Copy` made **already in the callee**. So it is not just a "returns wrong data" problem.

**Edit 2**

It turns out,that `Marshal.Copy` does not copy data, as stated in the documentation, but a pointer to the data.

`Marshal.ReadByte(oStructAddr)` does return the byte array's first byte, `Marshal.ReadByte(oStructAddr + 1)` its second byte, etc.

But how do I return this data in the `Out` argument?

Comment: Very well-written question. Could you check if it works when you make `HeaderStruct` a `Class` instead of `Structure`?. Structures may reside on the stack and I am not sure if it is possible to have a `GCHandle` for something on the stack. (Just as a temporary check, definitely not a permanent solution).

Comment: @NicoSchertler, thanks. This fails already on trying to obtain a handle for `oStruct` with `GCHandle.Alloc` (exception 'The object contains no primitive data.'). It executes when changing the `GCHandleType` to `Normal` (which doesn't pin it anymore!), but then I won't be able to use `oGCHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject`. Using `oStructAddr = CType(oGCHandle, IntPtr)` instead works, but then `SizeOf` complains, that the object can not be marshaled as an unmanaged structure.

Comment: @NicoSchertler : Pinning a structure should work, I've done so myself a couple of times without a problem. -- Herb: Based on the error I managed to find this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15549992 - Apparently it is thrown when you have a non-primitive variable in your struct (i.e. a variable pointing to a class).

Comment: @VisualVincent, the struct is as shown in the OP: it contains two shorts and one integer, in the actual case filled with 1, 2, 3 (represented in the file as `0x01 00 02 00 03 00 00 00`). No references to objects at all (except that everything). I updated the OP with some further findings. Obviously, Copy does not copy data as per documentation, but a pointer. (I can retrieve  the copy with `ReadByte` from that location, but have no idea how to populate the out argument.)

Comment: What do you mean by _"Copy does not copy data as per documentation, **but a pointer**"_? `Marshal.Copy()` copies the specified range of bytes to the specified destination memory address. However, you need to create the `GCHandle` with `GCHandleType.Pinned` and use `AddrOfPinnedObject` in order for this to work.

Comment: If that part works for your struct, have you tried changing the `ExtractStructure()` method to a function and making it return the resulting structure instead of using an out argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ExtractStructure` method needs to be rewritten like this:

```
'Expects to find a structure of type T at the actual position of the 
'specified filestream oFS. Reads this structure into a byte array and copies
'it to the structure variable specified in oStruct.
Public Shared Sub ExtractStructure(Of T As Structure) _
    (oFS As FileStream, ByRef oStruct As T)

    Dim iStructLen As Integer
    Dim abStreamData As Byte()
    Dim hStreamData As GCHandle
    Dim iStreamData As IntPtr

    'From the file's current position, read the number of bytes required to
    'fill the structure, into the byte array abStreamData.
    iStructLen = Marshal.SizeOf(oStruct)
    ReDim abStreamData(0 To iStructLen - 1)
    oFS.Read(abStreamData, 0, iStructLen)

    'Obtain a handle to the byte array, pinning it so that the garbage
    'collector does not move the object. This allows the address of the 
    'pinned structure to be taken. Requires the use of Free when done.
    hStreamData = GCHandle.Alloc(abStreamData, GCHandleType.Pinned)
    Try
        'Obtain the byte array's address.
        iStreamData = hStreamData.AddrOfPinnedObject()

        'Copy the byte array into the record.
        oStruct = Marshal.PtrToStructure(Of T)(iStreamData)
    Finally
        hStreamData.Free()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Works.

Answer (score 1):

I can not say for certain why the updated bytes copied to the pinned address are not reflected in the original structure, but I suspect that the interop-marshaller makes a copy.  see: [Copying and Pinning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/copying-and-pinning).

I do know that if you pin a byte array, that changes made by using Marshal.Copy are propagated back to the managed array.  With that said, here is an example that you should be able to use for your needs.

```
Dim lenBuffer As Int32 = Marshal.SizeOf(Of HeaderStruct)
Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(0 To lenBuffer - 1) {}
Dim gchBuffer As GCHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(buffer, GCHandleType.Pinned)
Dim hs As New HeaderStruct With {.MajorVersion = 4, .MinorVersion = 2, .Count = 5}

' copy to pinned byte array 
Marshal.StructureToPtr(hs, gchBuffer.AddrOfPinnedObject, True)
' buffer = {4, 0, 2, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0} ' array can be written to file

' change the data - simulates array read from file
buffer(0) = 1 ' MajorVersion = 1
buffer(2) = 3 ' MinorVersion = 3
buffer(4) = 2 '.Count = 2

' read from pinned byte array
Dim hs2 As HeaderStruct = Marshal.PtrToStructure(Of HeaderStruct)(gchBuffer.AddrOfPinnedObject)
gchBuffer.Free()
```

---

Edit:  Based on a comment, it seems that the OP believes that the technique shown above can not be implemented as generic methods for reading/writing to a stream.  So here is a copy/paste example.

```
Sub Example()
    Using ms As New IO.MemoryStream
        Dim hs As New HeaderStruct With {.MajorVersion = 4, .MinorVersion = 2, .Count = 5}
        Debug.Print($"Saved structure:  {hs}")
        WriteStruct(ms, hs)  'write structure to stream

        ms.Position = 0 ' reposition stream to start 
        Dim hs2 As New HeaderStruct ' target for reading from stream
        ReadStruct(ms, hs2)
        Debug.Print($"Retrieved structure: {hs2}")
    End Using
End Sub

Sub WriteStruct(Of T As {Structure})(strm As IO.Stream, ByRef struct As T)
    Dim lenBuffer As Int32 = Marshal.SizeOf(Of T)
    Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(0 To lenBuffer - 1) {}
    Dim gchBuffer As GCHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(buffer, GCHandleType.Pinned)
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(struct, gchBuffer.AddrOfPinnedObject, True)
    strm.Write(buffer, 0, lenBuffer)
    gchBuffer.Free()
End Sub

Sub ReadStruct(Of T As {Structure})(strm As IO.Stream, ByRef struct As T)
    Dim lenBuffer As Int32 = Marshal.SizeOf(Of T)
    Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(0 To lenBuffer - 1) {}
    strm.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
    Dim gchBuffer As GCHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(buffer, GCHandleType.Pinned)
    struct = Marshal.PtrToStructure(Of T)(gchBuffer.AddrOfPinnedObject)
    gchBuffer.Free()
End Sub

Public Structure HeaderStruct
    Public MajorVersion As Short
    Public MinorVersion As Short
    Public Count As Integer
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return $"MajorVersion = {MajorVersion}, MinorVersion = {MinorVersion}, Count = {Count}"
    End Function
End Structure
```

Output of `Example`:

> Saved structure:  MajorVersion = 4, MinorVersion = 2, Count = 5
>
> Retrieved structure: MajorVersion = 4, MinorVersion = 2, Count = 5

Comment: As stated in the (now updated) question, there are many different structures involved. Your approach would result in creating a class to handle each structure type individually, so I could omit declaring structures at all and make classes right from the start.

Comment: @herb, this answer demonstrates technique that answered your question. The fact that example used a hard coded type does preclude writing it as a generic.  See update for generic example.